# 'as much hot as' or 'much as hot as' or 'as much as hot'?

Tags: comparison

I am wondering about the use of as...as when I put adverb and adjective together. My aim is to write that in the past , weather was so hot and so it is now with similar extent of the past.

> It's as much hot as before.
>
> It's hot as much as before.
>
> It's much as hot as before.

which is right in grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We never speak of it being ***much*** hot—the ordinary intensive is ***very*** hot—so none of these is idiomatic.

And we do not use *very* in comparisons: there are no degrees of *very*, no *less very* or *more very*.

You may say something like *It is as extremely hot as before*, but this is an awkward and unnatural way of putting it. We would more likely say *It is extremely hot, just as hot as it was before*.

Comment: thanks for your answer and I'm asking one additional question. then is it right to say 'it is extremely hot, as much as it was before' or 'it is hot as extremely as it was before'?

Comment: @JBL W e l  l . . . they're not "incorrect", but I can't imagine anybody saying them.